# django python search result issue

Tags: python, django

I am creating a search feature. where the user will input name and city. results should appear like: name available in that city should show up.
**view.py**

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        srch = request.GET['srh']
        srch1 = request.GET['srh1']
        if srch:
            match = demo.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=srch))
            if srch1 in match:
                match2 = demo.objects.filter(Q(city__icontains=srch1))
                if match2:
                    return render(request, 'listing-search.html', {'sr':match2})
                else:
                    print('no result found')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    return render(request, 'listing-search.html')
```

**Template**

```
<form action="search/" method="get">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-1">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Find</span>
                      <input type="text" name= "srh" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name Type Karo" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" list="find">

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-2">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Location</span>
                      <input type="text" name="srh1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Shahabad" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" list="suggest-location">

                    </div>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size: 25px"></i></button>
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                  </form>
```

**Models.py**

```
class demo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please describe what's the issue. You're getting an error? What do you think `if srch1 in match` will do, you're checking if a string is in a set of `demo` objects.

Comment: Shouldn't be name a ForeignKey to city? As it is now, you can have duplicate cities with duplicate names, since none of them are unique..

Comment: @guillermochamorro : Thank you and yeah you are absolutely right. but right now i am just doing a demo if this function works or not. and its not working. i am not getting any results. once it would work, i will definitly use foreign key for city. moreover, i do want auto detect the city but thats another thing. right now whats the issue in this view.py

Comment: @dirkgroten : 1 believe srch1 will filter result of match.

Comment: That can't work. What do you want exactly? all `demo` objects where name contains srch *and* city contains srch1? Then you can just do `filter(name__icontains=srch, city__icontains=srch1)`. By the way, `Q` isn't needed here.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you for the reply and help. Ex. user enter John in 1st input (srh) and California in 2nd input (srh1). then result should show up all the John in California. This is what i want. i am trying to create a listing directory website. where i want the results based on location. Thank you

Comment: Just do the filter I mentioned above, that will return all objects that match both John and California.

Comment: `def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        srch = request.GET['srh']
        if srch:
            match = demo.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=srch)|
                                        Q(city__icontains=srch))
            if match:
                return render(request, 'listing-search.html', {'sr':match})
            else:
                print('no result found')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    return render(request, 'listing-search.html')` This works fine but i want results base on location by using 1 input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
srch = request.GET['srh']
srch1 = request.GET['srh1']
```

Use this:

```
 srch = request.GET.get('srh')
 srch1 = request.GET.get('srh1')
```

Comment: That’s not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @ayushgupta : getting an error: {TypeError at /search/
'method' object is not subscriptable
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/search/?srh=kumar&srh1=karnal
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'method' object is not subscriptable}

Comment: @dirkgroten : still not getting any results. if i just use one input and make change in the view.py according to that then it works fine. but i want result based on city.

Comment: You can do search for multiple fields in the DB like this. `match = demo.objects.get(city__icontains=srch1, name__icontains=srch)`

Comment: @ayushgupta : now not getting an error but still not getting the results. i simply wants a search function where a user can find results like all computer shop in a particular city. or any other location-based query.